# Recording computer sound and microphone through one device?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, microphone, recording

I have always been able to record computer sound and microphone input through stereo mix. I have done this on Windows XP and on Windows 7, but I re-installed Windows on my system and now I cannot figure out how to do this.

My recording software is Camstudio and sometimes I use Hypercam2. I can only select one recording device at once; that is why I need to put my mic and computer sound through one channel. One thing that worked was letting the speakers "listen" to the microphone but I hate the side effect of hearing myself through my speakers or headset.

I was hoping I could find the answer here. If not, I would like to hear some work arounds like other screen/sound recording software that can record sound from two devices at once. Perhaps I need one that can compress on the fly. Preferably free since I got really awesome video quality with the free programs I mentioned above.

-edit-
I forgot to mention that if I default my microphone my stereomixer goes "currently unavailable" and vice versa. A lot of people have exactly the same problem as I do but no answers anywhere. First they could run stereo mix and a microphone alongside each other just fine and upon reinstalling OS problems start to happen.

Comment: So do you have a microphone or not?  Your question is not exactly clear.

Comment: @Ramhound Not sure why it is unclear but the first phrase says that i have always been able to record sound and mic. 2nd phrase says i am unable to do that anymore which is the point of asking this question. If i would not have a mic anymore, i believe i could have figured out why it does not work anymore.

Comment: Your last statement leads me to the question "Do you or do you not have a microphone?"

Comment: Off course i have a microphone, otherwise the answer would be pretty simple right?

This is not a duplicate of that. I have ALWAYS been able to record mic and sound like i clearly state in the first paragraph. When i enable stereo mix my mic goes unavailable. I tried my mic in the front jack and the main jack.

Comment: VAC seems to do what i want, but why should i buy a license for it if i have always managed to pull this off with just a MIC and a free recording program? I have the same system as before and just did a clean install of windows 7.